# Making one to many or many to many relations with magento ORM

Tags: magento, entity-relationship, magento-1.5

I have a custom model/object for a magento extension I'm working on. I need to setup a relation to another object (for example, a relation to product).

I will need both One to Many and Many to Many relationships. How can I implement this using magento?

Comment: You can find all the needed info on the following page. It also briefly names all type of joins you can do: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento's ORM doesn't have built in management for traditional 1 to many or many to many relations.  You need to develop your own query strategy for this sort of thing.